# Como terminar ciclo While (PYTHON)

Tags: python

hice este programa que calcula tu edad, pero al intentar terminar el ciclo no funciona, se vuelve a repetir. Aún soy muy novato, ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
regreso = 1
while( regreso == 1):
    nom = (input ('Ingresa tu nombre: '))
    año = int(input("Ingresa año de nacimiento: "))
    actual = int(input("Ingresa año actual: "))
    años = actual - año
    print(f"Tienes en años = {años}")
    meses = años * 12
    print(f"Tienes en meses ={meses}")
    dias = años * 365
    print(f"Tienes en dias ={dias}")
    print("¿Quieres hacer otro calculo?")
    print("1. Si")
    print("2. No")
    opcion = input("Selecciona opcion: ")
    if opcion == "1":
        regreso = 1
    elif opcion == "2":
        break
```

Comment: Probe el código y funciona perfecto. Al ingresar el valor 2 en el teclado la ejecución termina.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código original funciona tal cual lo estipula el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Al tener break la variable regreso sigue teniendo el mismo valor, por lo tanto se sigue cumpliendo el while.
una solución seria:

```
if opcion == "1":
    regreso = 1
elif opcion == "2":
    regreso = 2
```

Comment: El código original funciona de hecho. Si bien tu cambio es correcto, es innecesario, por cuanto el `break` cumple la misma función.